# Авторизация по email или телефону - вопрос организации

Tags: php, авторизация, mysql

Всем привет.
В целом, сложного ничего нет. Проверяем что пришло, мыло или телефон и соответственно пытаемся из БД доставть email или телефон, проверить на существование + пароль.

Но не хочется писать говнокод)).
Как лучше организовать проверку данных и запрос из БД?
Буду благодарен за советы и помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Искать в БД по двум полям через OR

Comment: Может стоить определять что пришло, int или регуляркой хотя бы @ искать в строке, а уж после формировать условие где искать?

Comment: @drop_off, лично я не особо вижу смысл в регулярках. Поля у вас, по идее, должны быть уникальными, запрос не сложный. Другое дело, если вы проверяете на валидность, но это уже другая история.

Comment: ну не проблема проверять можно только телефон это совсем не int и мне кажется это лишнее. Совпадение может быть только одно.

Comment: Так и сделал.
Просто думал может какие нюансы есть...
Спасибо!